# Will Java 9 introduce a standard for code folding?

Tags: java, java-9, code-folding

I was reading about Java 9 new features, modules and changes. So far so good.
Will Java 9 introduce a standard for code folding?

Something similar to `#region` in VisualStudio or NetBeans' code folding comments.

```
[-] //  <editor-fold desc="Some description here">  
 |      public void method() {
 |          doSomething();
 |      }
 _  // </editor-fold>
```

If not, why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not predictors of the future.

Comment: @deceze Java 9 is already feature-complete. We know exactly the list of features that it includes. Please, search some info next time a little bit  prior to pressing the "close" button.

Comment: I vote to reopen. There are plenty of "Will Java 9 do X" or "How will X work in Java 9" questions.

Answer (score 3):

No, Java 9 will not introduce code folding. The full list of [Java 9 features](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/) does not mention code folding.

Comment: Maybe link to the [list of JEPs](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/) to give some background.

Comment: Any idea or insight on _why not_?

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna I have no insight, but I think there are two reasons: 1) Java has no pragmas, 2) Since IDEs already do it, there is no point to put into the standard

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna As far as I know there is no public discussion of that feature within the Java Community Process, so I would say the reasons against it are unknown. ;) Personally, I think this is best left to tools (doing this via comments), so there is no need to lift it into the language.